# How to thoroughly test an iOS app created with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, testing, tdd, bdd

Belonging to the world of web development, I am used to powerful testing techniques and tools like Chai, Sinon, Mocha, Jasmine, to name a few, as well as to wide support and community, well-written books with deep insights. There are all possible cases I can imagine that are covered with existing tools.

Now, learning iOS development with Swift, I wonder, how I can thoroughly test methods of my app using stubs and mocks, imitating connecting to web services asynchronously and get myself sure tests can be written in a clear manner, creating peace of mind for my aging body.

I find the community is not so wide in iOS development, especially, Swift, as a result of the language being not so long on the landscape.

Please share the best practices for testing that can help me to create solid predictably behaving apps.

Answer (score 0):

When developing iOS apps you have two possible test types you can use, one for unit testing, and one for acceptance testing. Those are referred in Xcode respectively as "Test Target" and "UI Test Target".

Within the tests target you can test all your app code by importing its Swift module using `@testable import MyAppName`, and then writing unit tests using `XCTest`, the framework provided by Apple.

On top on the tools provided by Apple, the FOSS community has developed other great testing libraries. In particular [Quick](https://github.com/Quick/Quick) is an testing framework that provides a syntax similar to Mocha.

When it comes to the UI tests target there is an important thing to be said: you can only test your app behaviour via those. There is no way to access the application code, everything is done through proxies that simulate the user's interaction with the UI. That is, in my opinion, for a good reason. The kind of tests one should write via tools that only allow UI interaction should be acceptance/funcitonal tests, which should only verify the app's behaviour. Not having access to the code is a good way to avoid misusing this tool.

> I wonder, how I can thoroughly test methods of my app using stubs and mocks, imitating connecting to web services asynchronously and get myself sure tests can be written in a clear manner, creating peace of mind for my aging body.

Going deeper:

> using stubs and mocks

Because of Swift's nature doing real mocking is quite hard. It's better to use fakes and doubles. There is also a great deal of literature online on why using mocks and stubs is seldom a good idea, for example [this](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/blog/2014/test-isolation-is-about-avoiding-mocks), [this](http://googletesting.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/testing-on-toilet-dont-overuse-mocks.html), [this](http://openmymind.net/2011/3/23/Stop-Using-Mocks/), and [this](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html).

> imitating connecting to web services asynchronously

After having said all that it is true that sometimes stubbing is useful, such in the case you highlight. A good library to do this is [OHHTTPStubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs).

> get myself sure tests can be written in a clear manner

I believe there are enough tools today to support writing clear and effective tests with little effort. The rest is up to you, your team, and the way you architect your app. As it is for any other programming language after all :D

If I can put a shameless plug in here, at the start of the year I wrote [a post covering the state of testing in the iOS plaform](http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/ios-testing-in-2015/), a lot of new things have happened since then, but it could be a good starting point if you want to dig deeper.